# Search files in directory and its sub directory in java

Tags: java

I would like to know faster way to Search files in directory and its sub directory in java. However, i know the parent directory but dont know the grandparent directory.
Eg c:/temp/test/*/111/abx.txt

I tried File.walkFileTree but not sure how to use it as is not working for me.

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Try adding your code in the question.

Comment: *I tried File.walkFileTree* -- We need *your* code to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s an example to show you how to search a file named “post.php” from directory “/Users/mkyong/websites” and all its subdirectories recursively.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class FileSearch {
private String fileNameToSearch;
private List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

public String getFileNameToSearch() {
    return fileNameToSearch;
}

public void setFileNameToSearch(String fileNameToSearch) {
    this.fileNameToSearch = fileNameToSearch;
}

public List<String> getResult() {
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    FileSearch fileSearch = new FileSearch();

    // try different directory and filename :)
    fileSearch.searchDirectory(new File("/Users/mkyong/websites"), "post.php");

    int count = fileSearch.getResult().size();
    if (count == 0) {
        System.out.println("\nNo result found!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("\nFound " + count + " result!\n");
        for (String matched : fileSearch.getResult()) {
            System.out.println("Found : " + matched);
        }
    }
}

public void searchDirectory(File directory, String fileNameToSearch) {
    setFileNameToSearch(fileNameToSearch);

    if (directory.isDirectory()) {
        search(directory);
    } else {
        System.out.println(directory.getAbsoluteFile() + " is not a directory!");
    }

}

private void search(File file) {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        System.out.println("Searching directory ... " + file.getAbsoluteFile());

        // do you have permission to read this directory?
        if (file.canRead()) {
            for (File temp : file.listFiles()) {
                if (temp.isDirectory()) {
                    search(temp);
                } else {
                    if (getFileNameToSearch().equals(temp.getName().toLowerCase())) {
                        result.add(temp.getAbsoluteFile().toString());
                    }

                }
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println(file.getAbsoluteFile() + "Permission Denied");
        }
    }

}

}
```